# Why is the render of my grease pencil object, all green?

Tags: materials, grease-pencil

In solid view, the colors are correct,
[image]

but when rendered, they aren't.
[image]

So when I render my file, I get just a green background.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You were painting with the Vertex Color option activated (which annoyingly isn't visible in Solid view mode, only in Material and Render view), as described in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196066/colors-look-much-different-in-solid-view-than-the-render-view?rq=1) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204714/how-can-i-reset-a-grease-pencil-objects-vertex-colors/204738#204738) questions

To resolve this, change from `Draw Mode` to `Vertex Paint` then in the `Paint` menu click on `Reset Vertex Color`.

[image]